# Can we minimize $m\log_m{n}$, given $n$?

Tags: optimization

If we are given $n$, a positive real, can we find a the positive real $m$ that minimizes the function:

$$m\log_m{n}$$

I'd prefer to find the function that gives a value for $m$, but I'm also interested in asymptotic bounds for $m$.

This is similar to [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481552/can-we-minimize-3m-2n-m-given-n).

**WHAT I HAVE**

I start with

$$x = m\log_m{n}$$
$$x = m\frac{\log n}{\log m}$$

Then, since $\log n$ is constant, we simply want to minimize
$$\frac{m}{\log m}$$

Is this correct?  I'm really hoping that someone can solve the original equation.  It's not homework.

Comment: If $n>1$ it is correct.

Comment: @Pocholapantera: We do have $n>1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're correct so far. Let $f(m)=\frac{m}{\log m}$; then

$$f'(m) = \frac{\log m - 1}{(\log m)^2} = 0 \iff m = e$$

Hence, $f$ has an extreme point at $e$. This is easily shown to be a global minimum.

Comment: Actually there is no global minimum since $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) = -\infty$.